# Using WriteAllText to write from ListView to the txt Document

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

My questions:

1.How can I place whole row with all subitems using  File.WriteAllText

2.How can i make every row present in txt file without last one getting deleted from txt file

```
  private void txtFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       File.WriteAllText(@txtFilePath.Text, listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);//Showing only one subitem
  }
```

Comment: Maybe try serializing the objects in your listview and then writing the json or xml to a text file.

Comment: Try AppendText(...) or read the file before writing in it